# gcc-12.2 dpkg-buildpackage need 32bit libs why?

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, gcc

Can someone please explain why gcc-12 src requires 32-bit packages?
I need to apply a patch to GCC-12.2 to upgrade it to 12.3, I don't want to build from src, so I just put a patch file to Debian/patches.

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.35    (miniconda3) 

dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package gcc-12
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution jammy-proposed
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by Matthias Klose <doko@ubuntu.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build .
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-x32 libx32gcc-s1 autoconf2.69 systemtap-sdt-dev sharutils gnat-11:native g++-11:native gdc-11:native lib32z1-dev libx32z1-dev dejagnu libgc-dev xsltproc docbook-xsl-ns
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
```

Thank you